# Mapping a hibernate collection based on a property

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm working with a legacy database and I'm trying to get hibernate to help me.

I have 3 tables that look something like:

```
Table results:
id (number pk)
info_id (varchar)
result (varchar)

Table info
id (number pk)
info_id (varchar)

Table registration
id (number pk)

Table letter
id (number pk)
registration_id
```

I'm only able to modify the Object for letter, and in this object I want to be able to get a (read only) list of results

```
public class Letter  {
    private Long  id;
    private Registration registration;  
    private List<Result> results;
}
```

The registration object already exists, and looks like this:

```
public class Registration  {
    private Long  id;
    private Info info;  
}
```

I'm trying to map the results object to the Letter object , and I was attempting something like this:

```
<list name="results" table="result" cascade="none" inverse="false">
          <key property-ref="registration.info.info_id"/>
          <index column="info_id "  />
        <one-to-many class="Result" />
    </list>
```

I basically want Hibernate to do a join through the chain of objects, and eventually get a SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM result,letter,info WHERE letter.info_id=info.info_id AND info.info_id=result.info_id
AND letter.id=?;
```

Is something like this viable in Hibernate?

**Edit:**
The tables info and registration have the same id.  So `info.id=registration.id`.  If needed I could add Info into the Letter object.

Comment: info does not has the registration_id.

Comment: I fixed the query. See my comments above.  Info and Registration have the same PK.

Answer (score 0):

As per the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758169/joining-two-unrelated-tables-in-hibernate?rq=1) . Relationship can be maintained only using the inner joins. So, Yes, you can do it. you may have to add the registration.id = info.id manually into the query.

Comment: How would I map this in XML.  Is there some way in the XML to specify "letter.info_id=info.info_id AND info.id=letter.registration_id" or similiar?

Comment: I have nt found anything. I think its not possible to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up creating a view and then used a normal "bag" mapping.